# How to get xparse to accept an argument as multiline one?

Tags: xparse

In `xparse`, the argument specifier `+b` in environment allows for entering multiple lines in the body of the document. Is there any equivalent when using `\NewDocumentCommand`. For example, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}{#1}

\begin{document}
    
\test{line}

\bigskip
\test{
    
line 1

line 2

}

\end{document}
```

Throws the errors

> Paragraph ended before \test was complete.

> Too many }'s. line 2} Too

> many }'s. }

Comment: The plus makes the argument long, +m

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. May you write this as an answer?